# ffmpeg process doesn't do anything - no error

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert a video between two file types, when run, nothing happens and no file is made. I've tried doing it with subprocess and os - both have the same result - nothing.

I can do the command fine through shell. I really want to be able to use this through python.

```
import subprocess

command = "ffmpeg -i X:/Desktop/twd.mp4 X:/Desktop/twd.mp3"
subprocess.run(command.split(),shell=True)
```

Comment: FFmpeg is probably displaying a message like: `File 'in.mp3' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N]` and waits for a key, but you can't see the console. Try adding `-y -report`. command = `"ffmpeg -i X:/Desktop/twd.mp4 X:/Desktop/twd.mp3 -y -report"`. The `-y` avoids the question, the `-report` creates a log file in the working folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> nothing happens and no file is made

This is very strange. Absolutely no text printed on console? I agree @Rotem's suggestion, but at the minimum the version info should print on your console (assuming you are using one of prebuilt binaries). BTW, `shell=True` is not needed and not recommended.

If you wish, you can give my [ffmpegio](https://python-ffmpegio.github.io/python-ffmpegio/) package a try, it might make your life a bit easier.

```
import ffmpegio

ffmpegio.transcode('X:/Desktop/twd.mp4','X:/Desktop/twd.mp3')
```

It should auto detect your ffmpeg binaries and run your example above.

Comment: This worked perfectly and has been the only thing to solve my problem! Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked for you! Pls upvote/answered if you could. thx